# Mudblazor HTML/CSS templates for UI design

Tags: mudblazor

Where do we see html templates for mudblazor?

The link says https://github.com/MudBlazor/Templates but I donot see any HTML/CSS templates.
I was looking for Themeforest kind of HTML templates where we can straight way use those templates for UI design.

Can some one point out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is preparing will used as a template.

And there is already a repo
https://github.com/MudBlazor/Templates